# Pandas: filter for 2nd day of the month

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following data.

```
            value
date                
2010-10-01  100
2010-10-02  200
2010-10-03  300
2012-10-02  100
2012-10-03  200
2012-10-04  300
2022-10-03  500
2022-10-04  600
```

I would like to filter for the 2nd day of the month for each year.  So i should end up with

```
date        value       
2010-10-02  200
2012-10-03  200
2022-10-04  600
```

Having a difficult time figuring out the most efficient way to do this without iteration/loops or lamdas.  I thought using the following should work, but does not.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay, BusinessDay, BMonthBegin
df = df[df.index == df.index + BMonthBegin(0) + BDay(1)]
```

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) for months periods and for second days use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with compare second values in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby(df.index.to_period('m')).cumcount().eq(1)]

print (df)
            value
date             
2010-10-02    200
2012-10-03    200
2022-10-04    600
```